# Only the largest eigenvalue

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

I would like to know the current state of the art in computing only the largest eigenvalue of a large $\mathcal{O}(2^{26})$, Hermitian, sparse matrix. There are several Fortran packages I know of which compute a subset of the eigenvalues.  I am wondering if there is any modern package which focuses only on the largest eigenvalue.  If the package only requires a matrix vector multiplication function instead of the whole matrix, even better.

Comment: Do you want to calculate the spectral radius?

Comment: Yes.  In particular, the largest and smallest (most negative) eigenvalues of the matrix I am working with are equal in magnitude.

Comment: is it a weighted bipartite graph or something?

Comment: No, it is basically a matrix representation of something similar to the Ising Hamiltonian (Kronecker product of a bunch of Pauli Matrices).

Comment: You might try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARPACK or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOBPCG. There are implementations / bindings in different scientific packages

Comment: Yes, those are the packages that I am aware of.  Was hoping/wondering if someone had come up with a specialized algorithm that focuses *only* on the largest eigenvalue.

Comment: Maybe with that size and proper matrix structure, some tensor-train methods might work faster (some random relevant paper to start with https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cpc.2013.12.017).
I understand that you're interesting in the largest eigenvalue only, but I'm not aware of any special algorithm in that case.

Comment: Thanks will look into this

Comment: I don't think there's any advantage to computing only the largest eigenvalue. Krylov subspace methods, which are still considered the gold standard in your setting, necessarily compute a subspace (it's in the name) and necessarily give some estimation of other large eigenvalues "for free". You _can_ ask the software for only the largest eigenvalue, which will have the advantage that it only needs to pass the error tolerance for the largest eigenvalue but this won't often make a tremendous difference. Happy to be proven wrong of course, but I'm not aware of a better method for only the largest.

Comment: Thanks for the input!  Yes, I am well aware of Krylov subspace methods -- if you would like to type up an answer for why no method of singling out the largest eigenvalue is feasible I would accept that